# Convert time into decimals in report

Tags: acumatica

I want to convert the time into decimal.

For example, 08:30 should be 8.5 and 0.45 should be 0.75.

What would be the best way to do these. Is there any function available or do I have calculate manually. Please suggest.

Comment: What is the DAC data type for the fields you are trying to convert? int timespan or datetime using the time portion?

Comment: It is all in string datatype like 08:30, 15:45, 00:20, so on an so forth.

Comment: from your answer it sounds like you are using the timespan (int) data types? Maybe you are storing the int value as a string however? we are using them too and yes the time is stored in total minutes.(as int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured,

Acumatica stores the time in minutes anyway which I can utilize to calculate into decimals.

For examples, 02:00 is stored as 120 and converting into decimal would be 120/60 which results in 2.0.